# Gnuplot: use a function to transform a column of a data file and plot the transformed data and the function

Tags: python, arrays, function, gnuplot, calculated-columns

I have a file that is called: `energy_vs_volume.dat` which is the following:

```
 # Volume       Energy
 123.598570   -1.883015140352E+03
 124.960411   -1.883015431207E+03
 126.122583   -1.883015514359E+03
 126.332431   -1.883015514750E+03
```

I have a function in that converts the `energy` to `pressure`, which is the following:

```
 E0=-1883.01544309
 B0=32.13
 V0=126.4025
 B0_prime=-0.95
 f0=(3.0/2.0)*B0
 f1(x)=((V0/x)**(7.0/3.0))-((V0/x)**(5.0/3.0))
 f2(x)=((V0/x)**(2.0/3.0))-1
 P(x)= f0*f1(x)*(1+(3.0/4.0)*(B0_prime-4)*f2(x))
```

I would like to plot in the same plot:

**Goal #1**:  The function `P(x)`

**Goal #2**:  All 4 rows of discrete data of `Energy` in the file `energy_vs_volume.dat`, convert it to pressure using the function, and plot these 4 points as `y axis: pressure`; `x axis: volume`

So far, I have achieved this:

```
 set encoding utf8
 set termoption enhanced

 E0=-1883.01544309
 B0=32.13
 V0=126.4025
 B0_prime=-0.95

f0=(3.0/2.0)*B0
f1(x)=((V0/x)**(7.0/3.0))-((V0/x)**(5.0/3.0))
f2(x)=((V0/x)**(2.0/3.0))-1
P_Birch_Murnaghan(x)= f0*f1(x)*(1+(3.0/4.0)*(B0_prime-4)*f2(x))

set xrange [123:138]

plot   P_Birch_Murnaghan(x)  with line lt -1 lw 3
```

This prints the continuous function of `P(x)`  -> **Goal #1**

In order to make **Goal #2** possible, I add to the script the following:

```
  plot  "energy_vs_volume.dat" using  (P(x)):2  with line lt -1 lw 3
```

or similar with `$`, but it does not work.

I would appreciate very much if you could help me.

**EDIT:**

I would need to know the exact values of the conversion (the pressures generated for the 4 data of volumes). Is there a way of redirecting the output to a file? something similar to the idea of plot `energy_vs_volume.dat" using 1:(P($1)) > file.txt` ?

Comment: @Christoph No... It does not work either...

Comment: Sorry, I misread the description. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
plot "energy_vs_volume.dat" using 1:(P($1))
```

to apply the function `P(x)` to your data. To write the calculated values to a file, wrap the plot command in `set/unset table` pair:

```
plot "energy_vs_volume.dat" using 1:(P($1))
set table "output.dat"
replot
unset table
```

The generated file contains three columns, the values as given by the `using` statement, and in the third column a character which indicates if the values were in range (`i`), out of range (`o`) or undefined (`u`).

Comment: Yes, but only one thing: it should be: `plot "energy_vs_volume.dat" using 1:(P($1))` ... ok? Great job! But, there is one thing left I forgot to ask in the main question (now edited): I would need to know the exact values of the conversion (the pressures generated for the 4 data of volumes). Is there a way of redirecting the output to a file? something similar to the idea of `plot "energy_vs_volume.dat" using 1:(P($1)) > file.txt` ? (I am really sorry for the moment I cannot give you a +1 because I have got less than 15 reputation)